# Copy a Certain text from an .ini to the .bat

Tags: batch-file

For example I bave a **ID.ini** and a **Setup.bat**

I would like to copy this line `"C:\Program Files\myapp"` from the `"ID.ini"`
`Install Directory="C:\Program Files\myapp"`

I would like to paste the line `"C:\Program Files\myapp"` to the .bat

```
@echo off
echo Install Directory= (paste it here!)
```

Comment: Ctl+C, Ctl+V  .  Or Edit>Copy, Edit>Paste

Comment: Glad to meet you, I'm 17. :-)

Comment: I remember this stuff when I was 10... Age is a poor excuse for laziness.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
for /f "tokens=1,*delims==" %%i in (id.ini) do if /i "%%i"=="Install Directory" echo(%%j
```